# OO Spring REST API design - a form conversion or inheritance

Tags: java, spring, rest, oop, api-design

I have the following scenario (simplified) in Spring REST API.

```
public class FooService 
{
    public void createFoo(FooData data) { ... }
}
public class FooController
{
    public void makeFooAnymous(AnymousFooForm aif) { ... }
    public void makeFooUser(UserFooForm uif) { ... }
}
```

Both endpoints makeIssueAnymous and makeIssueUser want to call createIssue because they do the same, but have some differences in API.

**Solution I**

In controller, both endpoints call a method

```
private <T> void createFooUsing(T fooForm, Function<T, FooData> formToDataConverter)
{
    // doSomeCommonConversionLogic
    try
    {
        createSomeResource();
        fooService.saveFoo(formToDataConverter.apply(fooForm), andMaybeAnotherParam);
    } catch (SomeExcp e) { doSomeThingSpecial() }
}
```

And form classes are like this:

```
class UserFooForm
{
     public String someData;
     public FooData toFooData(String otherField) { ... } 
}
class AnymousFooForm
{
     public String someDatas;
     public String otherField;
     public FooData toFooData(int paramFromPath) { ... } 
}
```

And code in cotroller method is like this:

```
public void makeFooUser(@RequestBody UserFooForm fooForm)
{
    return createFooUsing(fooForm, f -> f.toFooData("abc"));
}
public void makeFooAnymous(@RequestBody UserFooForm fooForm)
{
    return createFooUsing(fooForm, f -> f.toFooData(123));
}
```

**Solution II:**

Turn FooData into interface

```
interface FooData {
    String getSomeData();
    String getOtherField();
}
```

And make UserIssueForm and AnymousIssueForm implement the interface, copy the "doSomeCommonConversionLogic" and just pass it to createIssue service method.

```
public void makeFooUser(@RequestBody UserFooForm fooForm)
{
    // doSomeCommonConversionLogic
    try
    {
        createSomeResource();
        fooForm.prepare("abc");
        fooService.saveFoo(fooForm, andMaybeAnotherParam);
    } catch (SomeExcp e) { doSomeThingSpecial() }
}
public void makeFooAnymous(@RequestBody AnymousFooForm fooForm)
{
    // doSomeCommonConversionLogic
    try
    {
        createSomeResource();
        fooForm.prepare(123);
        fooService.saveFoo(fooForm, andMaybeAnotherParam);
    } catch (SomeExc e) { doSomeThingSpecial() }
}
```

That would be great if there wasn't that common code. It's HTTP - related and I don't want to have it in the service.

Which is better? And maybe something else?